# Rails 3: Can't add correct route to legacy code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, erb, legacy-code

Believe you can help me.

I'm trying to add new functionality to legacy code (Typo). But it seems that there is some problem about routing.

In the project routes are generated the following way:

```
%w{advanced cache categories comments content profiles feedback general pages
resources sidebar textfilters themes trackbacks users settings tags redirects seo post_types }.each do |i|
match "/admin/#{i}", :to => "admin/#{i}#index", :format => false
match "/admin/#{i}(/:action(/:id))", :to => "admin/#{i}", :action => nil, :id => nil, :format => false
end
```

My functionality is about merging articles. For that I've added new action in the **/admin/content** controller:

```
def merge
#some code here
end
```

A piece of a view partial (_form.html.erb) added by me:

```
  <% if current_user.admin? and !@article.id.nil?%>
    <div class=''>  
      <h4><%= _("Merge Articles") %></h4>
      <%= label_tag :merge_with, 'Article ID' %><%= text_field_tag :merge_with, nil, :size => 20 %>
      <%= button_to 'Merge', admin_content_merge_path(:id => @article.id) %>
    </div>
  <%end%>
```

This partial is rendered by another partial (_edit.html.erb)

```
<%= form_tag(form_action, :id => "#{form_type}_form", :enctype => "multipart/form-data", :class => className) do %>

  <%= render :partial => "form" %>

<% end %>
```

And finally _edit.html.erb is rendered by view new.html.erb

```
<%= render "admin/shared/edit", { :form_type => "article", :form_action => { :action => "new", :id => @article.id , :class => ('autosave')} } %>
```

The problem is how to write a correct route for the controller action above which will allow me to render an edit page containing newly merged article. I wrote:

```
  match "/admin/content/merge/:id" => "admin/content#merge",:as => 'admin/content/merge'
```

**rake routes** output:

```
admin_content_merge        /admin/content/merge/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"admin/content", :action=>"merge"}
```

But the new or edit action is being invoked as I can see.

Apparently, my route is wrong, isn't it?

Could you please help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Up-to-date **new.html.erb**:

```
<% @page_heading = _('New article') %>

<%= render "admin/shared/edit", { :form_type => "article", :form_action => { :action => "new", :id => @article.id , :class => ('autosave')} } %>
<% if current_user.admin? and !@article.id.nil?%>
<%= form_tag "/admin/content/merge/#{@article.id}" do %>
  <h4><%= _("Merge Articles") %></h4>
  <%= label_tag :merge_with, 'Article ID' %>:
  <%= text_field_tag :merge_with %><br />
  <%= submit_tag "Merge" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the hint from the course:

***HINT:Nesting  is invalid in HTML.***

That means that you can't nest form tags, don't put the form tag in another form tag, your nested form wont be able to do a correct action.

Since you have to put your code at the end of the page, try and see how to do it with having your merging form tag below the main edit article form tag. So basically you can find where the big form tag ends and put it below it.

Try to see if you can figure it out, and if not, don't hesitate to ask :)

Btw. I think everybody had some problem with this

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Hm... as far as I know, nesting is invoking of some form helper inside a partial, e.g. **form_for**, which is illegal I suppose. Where is nesting in my case?

Comment: You probably have a nested form since you get that error (the same thing happened to me). Nested form_for would be a **form_for** inside of another **form_for**.

Comment: Do you see where you have put your code in? You put the form and then you render that partial inside another form. that is nesting forms :)

Comment: Wow! Now it works. Just made it the way you described. Besides, there was even no need to write a specific route in **routes.rb**. So thanks a lot for help!) 
P.S. Updated initial post.

Comment: :) no problem glad i could help, i has the same problem!